# Matrix elements represent by double pointers in structure C

Tags: pointers, matrix, structure

I need to fill elements of 3 matrix in separate function.
Individuall matrix is respresent by structure MAT which includes dimensions and double pointer for elements.
I need simple solution, I am actually beginer. Is it necessary to use dynamic allocation of memory in this case? If it is possible to solve this assigment with and without dynamic allocation of memory I am interested for both solutions

This is what I done so far, so it would be nice if someone could continue this code, thanx :

```
     typedef struct mat {double **elem; int n, m;} MAT;
     void fill_it(MAT *a);

  int main()
  {
  MAT m[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      printf("Input elements of %d. matrix\n",i+1);
      fill_it(m+i);
    }   
  }
      
     void fill_it(MAT *a)
      {
       printf("Input matrix dimension\n");
       printf("n:");scanf("%d",&a->n);
       printf("m:");scanf("%d",&a->m);
       
      ......
       }
```